# Revising an one liner

Tags: bash, scripting, awk, grep

I've cobbled together a one-liner so I can quickly find any drives that have medium errors on a server. This is like so:

```
/var/lib/einarc/tools/adaptec_arcconf/cli getlogs 1 device tabular | egrep 'serialNumber|mediumErrors|vendorID' | awk '{$2="";print}' | awk '/^vendorID  WDC/{p=1}p' | grep -C1 'mediumErrors  [1-9]'
```

While this works perfectly fine on servers that have Western Digital drives, there's ones that are Seagate and because of this the one liner doesn't work on them because of:

```
awk '/^vendorID  WDC/{p=1}p'
```

The raw output of the tabular logs on the two servers looks something like this.

```
Western Digital:


  driveErrorEntry             
     smartError ....................... false
     vendorID ......................... LSI CORP
     serialNumber ..................... 
     wwn .............................. 41121562336217ea
     deviceID(T:L) .................... 0(0:0)
     productID ........................ SAS2X26 
     numParityErrors .................. 0
     linkFailures ..................... 0
     hwErrors ......................... 0
     abortedCmds ...................... 10
     mediumErrors ..................... 0
     smartWarning ..................... 0
      driveErrorEntry             
         smartError ....................... false
         vendorID ......................... WDC     
         serialNumber ..................... WD-WCAW25942651
         wwn .............................. 0000000000000000
         deviceID(T:L) .................... 13(13:0)
```

Seagate:

```
Controllers found: 1

   ControllerLog                  
      controllerID ..................... 0
      type ............................. 0
      time ............................. 1365801225
      version .......................... 3
      tableFull ........................ false

      driveErrorEntry             
         smartError ....................... false
         vendorID ......................... LSI CORP
         serialNumber ..................... 
         wwn .............................. 411313200032c06a
         deviceID(T:L) .................... 0(0:0)
         productID ........................ SAS2X26 
         numParityErrors .................. 0
         linkFailures ..................... 0
         hwErrors ......................... 0
         abortedCmds ...................... 12
         mediumErrors ..................... 0
         smartWarning ..................... 0
```

The output I'm looking to get is as follows:

```
serialNumber  WD-WMAYP5242602
mediumErrors  457
vendorID  WDC
serialNumber  WD-WMAYP3262235
mediumErrors  2
```

I want to make sure that I'm not filtering out vital information because one server doesn't have WDC drives, but at the same time I also don't want any information that doesn't directly involve the harddrives - i.e. the the controller output should all be ignored regardless of the kind of drive installed.

Can anyone suggest a way to do this that would work (in bash)?

Comment: Is it just me or is the values in the expected output NOT present in the provided logs?

Comment: @FredrikPihl nope it's not just you! Striketh your output can not be mapped from your input.

Comment: The output should contain the medium errors, vendor I'd and serial number.  Column 2 is always going to vary depending on the drives in each server

Comment: 'One-liner' is a pejorative epithet, especially when the one line is so massively long as in your example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my solution.

```
/var/lib/einarc/tools/adaptec_arcconf/cli getlogs 1 device tabular | egrep 'serialNumber|mediumErrors|deviceID' | awk '{$2="";print}' | grep -C2 'mediumErrors  [1-9]'
```

I slightly modified it to look for the deviceID instead of the vendorID since that's more useful anyway, and then I could simply remove the awk that was filtering WDC drives. The -C2 instead of the -C1 also ensures that even if the formatting of the output is a little different than expected, I still get all of my data.